# Django - how to pass a list in the URL?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is a beginners question...but here it goes.

I have a url subject_owner?owner_ids=61,62,63

What should be the urls.py entry to forward this url to the attached view?

I have tried few options...but none of them work and give an error back, the following will not work, but something similar to that should do the trick.

```
url(r'^v1/subject_owner/(?P<owner_id>[a-z0-9]+)$',
    views.SubjectByOwnerViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
```

---

Thank you for the answers. One more question, primarily about wiring...

I have made corresponding entries in urls.py in the url_pattern block...

```
    url(r'^v1/subject_owner/',
           views.SubjectByOwnerViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
```

And wired in **init**.py the following...

```
    from .subject_owner import SubjectByOwnerViewSet
```

Still the view is not getting picked up when I test through postman. Is there anywhere else we need to wire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is *not* part of the URL path, it is the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Django captures this in [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET). You do *not* parse this in the `url(..)` or `path(..)`. Your path does not capture that part, so your `url` still looks like:

```
url(
    r'^v1/subject_owner/',
    views.SubjectByOwnerViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})
)
```

You can access this in the view with `request.GET['owner_id']`.

For example in your `SubjectByOwnerViewSet`:

```
class SubjectByOwnerViewSet(ViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        owner_id_list = self.request.GET['owner_id'].split(',')
        return super().get_queryset(*args,**kwargs).filter(
            owner__in=owner_id_list
        )
```

of course you can access this in other methods as well, the above is just a hypothetical use case.